Error handling in Swift async/throws: During my error handling, I always face print("DEBUG: Unknown error occurred: ...")
everyone. I am new to Swift, and trying to handle custom errors in my project. Unfortunately, during errors I always encounter print("DEBUG: Unknown error occurred: ..."). For example, if error is 'invalidURL' I have 'DEBUG: Unknown error occurred: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.' and so on.
Any ideas how i can make it work? Thank you in advance.
Here is my function from DataService:
func getEnemy() async throws -> Enemy {

        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            throw EnemyAPIError.invalidURL
        }
        
        let (data, response) = try await urlSession.data(for: url)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            print("DEBUG: Bad Server Response")
            throw EnemyAPIError.badServerResponse
        }
        
        guard httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to fetch with status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            throw EnemyAPIError.invalidStatusCode(statusCode: httpResponse.statusCode)
        }
        
        guard !data.isEmpty else {
            throw EnemyAPIError.invalidData
        }
        
        let enemy = try JSONDecoder().decode(Enemy.self, from: data)
        return enemy
    }

In my viewModel I am trying to handle custom errors:
func fetchEnemyAsync() async  {
do{
self.enemy = try await networkService.getEnemy()
} catch let error as EnemyAPIError {
self.errorMessage = error.customDescription
print("DEBUG: Error occurred: (error.customDescription)")
}
catch {
print("DEBUG: Unknown error occurred: (error.localizedDescription)")
self.errorMessage = "(error.localizedDescription)"
}
}

My custom errors:
enum EnemyAPIError: Error{
case invalidData
case invalidURL
case jsonParsingFailure
case badServerResponse
case requestFailed(description: String)
case invalidStatusCode(statusCode: Int)
case unknownError(error: Error)

    var customDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .invalidData:
            return "Invalid data"
        case .invalidURL:
            return "Invalid URL"
        case .jsonParsingFailure:
            return "Failed to parse JSON"
        case .badServerResponse:
            return "Bad Server Response"
        case .requestFailed(let description):
            return "Request failed: \(description)"
        case .invalidStatusCode(let statusCode):
            return "Invalid status code: \(statusCode)"
        case .unknownError(let error):
            return "\(error.localizedDescription)"
        }
    }

}

In my viewModel i've tried to handle errors like this, but it doesn't work. I thought, it will catch any error of type EnemyAPIError.
func fetchEnemyAsync() async  {
do{
self.enemy = try await networkService.getEnemy()
} catch let error as EnemyAPIError {
self.errorMessage = error.customDescription
print("DEBUG: Error occurred: (error.customDescription)")
}



When you do a « try » , put it in a do/catch block , especially for JSON decoding.

Be aware that the error thrown by  JSONDecoder is not an EnemyAPIError and to get the real decoding error you must not print the localizedDescription string, you have to handle the different DecodingErrors.

”A server with the specified hostname could not be found.” is not from invalidURL but thrown by urlSession and as already mentioned you are not catching and translating that error to an  EnemyAPIError error

@JoakimDanielson, thanks for your answer. Could you please show an example of code, because I am trying to make it in docatch, and have same issue
